# Laptop does not wake up after suspend

Tags: 14.04, graphics, suspend, 15.04, wakeup

This happens randomly. I have an [Hp Pavilion 17](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04511132)

When I suspend my laptop (whether by closing the lid or any other way) sometimes it does not wake up afterwards. The only solution is to force-shut down my computer by holding the power button, and then turn it back on. It's getting annoying as I can't really predict when it will actually happen. I've searched for solutions online but I couldn't find anything useful.

Somewhere it was suggested that it was an Nvidia issue, but i don't have an Nvidia card. Upgrading from  14.04 to 15.04 didn't help either.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Here is a long solution which i have not tried. https://askubuntu.com/questions/784714/where-to-troubleshoot-wake-up-from-suspend

Comment: [A workaround I got. It is far better than rebooting your system. Ubuntu goes into file system check etc due to force boot. Now, just lock your system before you leave your system.](https://askubuntu.com/a/908843/118354)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in which when I closed my laptop lid I had to force power off my machine and turning it up again before I could used it.
here is a trial proposal how I solved it.

-check if the acid daemon is enabled an running on your Debian system

## systemctl is-enabled acpid.service

if disabled

- ## systemctl enable acpid.service

-# systemctl start acpid.service

to verify it is running use

## systemctl status acpid.service

I hope it helps you.