# Where to troubleshoot wake-up from 'suspend'?

Tags: 16.04, suspend, wakeup

CONFIGURATION:

- HP Elitebook 8440p: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
- Ubuntu 16.04

SYMPTOMS of failed wake-up from suspend:

1. "TV Static"
2. black screen: suspend invoked by lid-close
3. white screen: suspend invoked by power button

What test can be done to determine the root cause \ corrective action?

Update: Driver status screenshot

[image]

Comment: I started facing this problem after various updates. Asus R558U.

Comment: Could you try the solution posted here https://askubuntu.com/q/904860/26246

Comment: 0
down vote Solution: Upgrade to kernel 4.13.1 https://askubuntu.com/questions/907899/cant-wake-up-from-suspend/956489#956489

Comment: Solution: Upgrade to kernel 4.13.1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/907899/cant-wake-up-from-suspend/956489#956489

Answer (score 5):

You should start from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging, and more specifically:

- [Debugging Kernel Suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) -- Help debugging kernel suspend/resume problems
- [Debugging Kernel Hibernate](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate) -- Help debugging kernel hibernate/resume problems

Then probably you should submit a bug report. If you get confused or need help on what you did find you may ask here.

- One thing may worth to try:

  1. Switch to console tty1 using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
  2. Login & run

     ```
     sudo pm-suspend
     ```

  If it does suspend, try resume

  1. Press power on
  2. When you are back to tty1, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to Desktop (tty7)
- Second way to try, it works for me in XFCE/Mate 16.04 with nvidia proprietary driver.

  1. After resume, switch to console tty1 using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
  2. Login
  3. Search for any screen-saver or screen-locker

     ```
     ps aux | grep -i -e saver -e locker
     ```

     Example: `light-locker`, `xscreensaver` ...
  4. Kill them

     ```
     sudo kill <PID>
     ```
  5. Check again with step 3

     It fine, either they disappear or have different PID's (means they restarted)
  6. Switch back to tty7, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to Desktop

Comment: It freezes for me after trying to switch back to tty7 (ASUS X555UF)

Comment: @vp_arth, That a quick trick that work for some cases. As it doesn't work, you should go with bug report, I already included the link to debugging instructions.

Answer (score 1):

use the NVIDIA proprietary drivers listed in the screenshot you provided.
Choose the top choice:
NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96 from nvidia-340

Answer (score 1):

For me, what works, is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, to wake the computer up,
then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, to go back to your desktop.

Same issue on my HP Stream 11 (with Intel Celeron N3060)

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, I was able to hibernate my Inspiron 531.

Edit the file:

`/var/lib/polkit-1 /localauthority/ ...`

or

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/...`

Create a Desktop Entry file as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding = UTF-8
Version = 1.0
Type = Application
Terminal = true
Icon [en_US] = gnome-panel-launcher
Exec = sudo pm-hibernate
Name = Hibernate
```

Comment: Please consider adding comments to explain either why it works on your Inspiron and how you arrived at this solution.

Comment: Edit what file exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is not a solution but a workaround you can live till real solution is available.

I tried many solutions including updating NVIDIA driver to recent ones. But nothing worked. 
I upgraded to 17.1 but no solution. Now, in 17.1, I see when I lock screen and it goes to suspend then it can wakeup correctly. So, try in older version as well as workaround. Otherwise, it was very painful to reboot system. Now, just lock before you leave your system.