# How can I uninstall specific NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I installed the latest driver 375.26 for the NVIDIA GTX 1060 GPU using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-375
```

This operation *seems* to have installed the 367.57 and 370.28 drivers additionally.

[image: drivers]

How can I remove the 367 and 370 drivers?

Comment: Why do you need to remove them ?  Those are probably not on your system only in repositories as an OPTION to download and install.

Comment: @GreggD I'm having issues with the computer waking from suspend. I thought the other drivers might cause conflicts and would like to remove them if they are on my system.

Comment: You might start [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/784714/where-to-troubleshoot-wake-up-from-suspend) this seems to be an XY problem.

Comment: GreggD means that nvidia-370 and nvidia-367 you saw here are probably just available for you to choose, not installed. You can check this with command `dpkg -l | grep nvidia-` in a terminal.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin After running the command it appears the 375 driver is the only one installed. Since there no other drivers installed this answers my question. Feel free to submit this as answer below.

Comment: This is a persistent Ubuntu issue that I have had for many years. It is not "relevant to a very specific period of time". It can be reproduced. It has never NOT happened for me. I tried sudo apt purge blahblah after checking with dpkg -l | grep nvidia, and, interestingly, the autocomplete pretends that the old nvidia packages/modules don't exist, but, if you manually type them, it agrees, and purges them. HOWEVER, after purging, they still show up in the Software & Updates list screencapped above! This has affected me from at least 16.xx to 19.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is meant to be **general information** for you and all the other users reading your question. There are several different graphics drivers available in the Ubuntu repositories - BUT ... there is only one single graphics driver installed and in use when the Ubuntu operating system boots !

So when you install the NVIDIA drivers 375.26 and had, let's say the drivers 367 installed before, the old drivers automatically are getting uninstalled and the new drivers - in your case 375 - are getting installed and are active after rebooting the operating system. To check which drivers are installed, execute the following command : `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia`. Example :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
nvidia-375                  install  
nvidia-opencl-icd-375       install  
nvidia-prime                install  
nvidia-settings             install
```

Of course you can alternatively remove the old drivers manually before installing new drivers.
The command to remove the currently installed drivers would be : `sudo apt purge nvidia*`

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, please suggest a way to check what drivers are actually installed on the computer.

Comment: You might want to add that `nvidia-375` provides, conflicts with and replaces `nvidia-persistenced, xorg-driver-binary`. That will instruct the package manager to remove previous `nvidia-*` packages on installation.

Comment: @DavidFoerster : nvidia-persistenced will not be installed automatically and also not as a dependency when you install any proprietary NVIDIA drivers, you would have to install it intentionally. That's why I didn't mention it and also because it might have caused some confusion, which I wanted to avoid. :)

Comment: I never claimed that `nvidia-persistenced` will be installed automatically. I merely cited the Deb package status file entries. and explained the consequential behaviour of the package manager for them.

Comment: This does not show manually installed drivers. Is there a good way to show ALL installed drivers?

Comment: @Hakaishin You can list all loaded kernel drivers and modules by executing `sudo lsmod`. :)