# I am unable to get proper resolution after installing ubuntu 16.04 alongwith window 10 dualboot

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, asus, display-resolution

I tried installing ubuntu 16.04 on ASUS GL502VM but I am getting 800x600 resolution but the screen resolution is 1920x1080 which is disturbing. I tried changing it from the display preferences but I see no other options. what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/330293/how-do-i-set-a-monitor-resolution-that-is-not-available-in-the-display-settings)?

Comment: @fakeda Yes I tried that. It shows some error in step two,                                                  xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19 Current serial number in output stream:  19

Comment: Forget the above instruction, for a moment. The Asus ROG GL502VM includes a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 for which the latest Nvidia proprietary drivers are required.

Comment: @CelticWarrior , so should I update the drivers? if yes then how?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/865454/how-can-i-uninstall-specific-nvidia-drivers  <- Use this as a reference. The procedure is actually in the question itself, the other user was just worried about something he shouldn't be. As soon as you add the PPA and apt update, the only thing left to do is to search for Additional Drivers (in the screenshot), select and apply the 375 version and reboot when done. It should automatically adjust for the native resolution.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, after installing the drivers I restarted my pc and now it's unable to get Gui for Ubuntu. I am stuck here. I got screen at the top its written /dev/sda7: clean 224276/7397376 files, 1815373/29583104 blocks.

Comment: Have you followed the same process as described in the question I linked above?

Comment: I updated the drivers compatible to NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060. It's working fine but in insecure boot. The newly installed driver is crashing my ubuntu. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can add missing resolutions to Ubuntu 12.04 using xrandr.

First, use cvt to create a new resolution mode

```
sudo cvt 1920 1080 60
```

Part of the output should be similar to this: "Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync" (w/o the quotes).

Next, declare a new resolution mode.

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Next, find out the name of your video device.

```
sudo xrandr -q
```

For me,It was VGA1.Your name should something like this.
Once you know the name of your device, you can, finally, add your new resolution mode to the device/system.N.B.YOu need to change VGA1 as yours.

```
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Expecting this will help you. 
If you want more [Adding Undetected Resoulation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution/#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

Comment: I had to update the drivers compatible to NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060. It's working fine but in insecure boot. The newly installed driver is crashing my ubuntu. I don't know why?