# Ubuntu boots to black screen after restart but works after being shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2

I've been facing a strange issue with my Ubuntu for a considerable time now.

If I reboot it, it will be stuck in a black screen after grub. If I completely shutdown it, it will boot normally.

It's been this way long before I upgraded to 17.04. I think it started happening when I migrated my "primary partition" from an HDD to a SSD.

How do I fix this?

OS Info:

- Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit (dev branch)
- GNOME Shell 3.24.0
- NVIDIA 378.13
- GRUB 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2 (for dual boot with WIN10)
- Samsung SSD 850 250GB (Primary SSD)
- TOSHIBA MK6461GS 640GB (Secondary HDD)
- Partition information:

  ```
  sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
  ├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
  ├─sda2   8:2    0    60G  0 part /media/WIN10
  ├─sda3   8:3    0 124.7G  0 part /media/SSD
  ├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
  ├─sda5   8:5    0  40.1G  0 part /
  └─sda6   8:6    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
  sdb      8:16   0 596.2G  0 disk 
  ├─sdb1   8:17   0  39.2M  0 part 
  ├─sdb2   8:18   0     8G  0 part 
  ├─sdb4   8:20   0     1K  0 part 
  └─sdb5   8:21   0 588.1G  0 part /media/HDD
  ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some more meddling, I've found a solution: just edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=pci"` and run `sudo update-grub` (or do the same using grub-customizer).

Other possible [values](http://michalorman.com/2013/10/fix-ubuntu-freeze-during-restart/):

- warm - don’t set the cold reboot flag
- cold - set the cold reboot flag
- bios - reboot by jumping through the BIOS (only for X86_32)
- smp (reboot by executing reset on BSP or other CPU - only for X86_32)
- triple - force a triple fault - init
- kbd - use the keyboard controller. cold reset (default)
- acpi - use the RESET_REG in the FADT
- efi - use efi reset_system runtime service
- pci - use the so-called “PCI reset register”, CF9
- force - avoid anything that could hang