# Computer fails to load after reboot but not after shutdown

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I have a dual boot computer running Ubuntu 16.04 (Alongside windows). Recently after some installations (Nvidia drivers for GPU) we are experiencing a weird situation where the computer booting stops and hangs with a blinking cursor before showing grub options if we reboot it (either by the reboot button, sudo reboot or sudo shutdown -r). However, it boots successfully if we shutdown it with its button and start again.
Has anyone encountered such an issue?

I've tried following [Ubuntu boots to black screen after restart but works after being shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904860/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-after-restart-but-works-after-being-shutdown/906397) , but it doesn't help.
output of dmesg | grep -i nvidia

```
[    2.301025] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.301032] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    2.321225] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.330564] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
[    2.332852] nvidia 0000:65:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    2.381799] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  410.104  Tue Feb  5 22:58:30 CST 2019 (using threaded interrupts)
[    2.383505] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  410.104  Tue Feb  5 22:56:44 CST 2019
[    2.384250] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00006500] Loading driver
[    2.384251] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:65:00.0 on minor 0
[    2.998685] caller os_map_kernel_space.part.9+0x109/0x140 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
[    3.485510] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.1/sound/card1/input13
[    3.485581] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.1/sound/card1/input14
[    3.485626] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[    3.485663] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:64/0000:64:00.0/0000:65:00.1/sound/card1/input16
```

output of cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-70-generic root=UUID=6c06757f-61f6-4cb2-a296-0fb31a9b7875 ro quiet splash reboot=pci vt.handoff=7
```

Using Nvidia Gforce Rtx 2080, driver installed is 410.104

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please post  `dmesg | grep -i nvidia`. Which graphic card are you using? Which Nvidia drivers did you install? Could you post `cat /proc/cmdline`. We need more infos in order to help you.

Comment: I've added the information you asked for. Thanks!

Comment: Tried them. Nothing worked...

Comment: I know I used to have an issue with a boot loop when using nVidia drivers, I got around it with setting "nomodeset" in "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX".  I don't know if it's still relevant now though.