# Screen is black or white after resume from suspend, but ssh connection from another machine succeeds

Tags: nvidia, ssh, suspend, services

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with mate desktop and occasionally when I try to resume after suspend it fails so that the screen is black and it does not respond to keyboard / mouse.

From another machine (A) I can still take a ssh connection to this black screen machine (B). Using this ssh connection from machine A I have tried to pm-suspend the machine B. Suspend seems to work, but again resume after pm-suspend fails: Machine B screen remains black or white and it does not respond to keyboard / mouse. Ssh connection seems to work always after resume.

After failed resume I have tried following suspend commands with quirks (see man pm-suspend):

```
pm-suspend 
pm-suspend --quirk-dpms-on
pm-suspend --quirk-dpms-suspend
pm-suspend --quirk-s3-bios
pm-suspend --quirk-s3-mode
pm-suspend --quirk-vbe-post
pm-suspend --quirk-vga-mode-3
```

But nothing helps.

Finally I have run shutdown from machine A ssh connection to get machine B down and restarted. After restart screen works normally.

1) Are there any other possibilities to get the desktop visible with the help of this ssh connection e.g. to restart services etc in order to avoid machine B shutdown?

2) Graphics card is: GeForce GTX 750 1GB. Are there any specific quirks or quirk combinations for this card?

Comment: See killing screen-saver/-locker helps as explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/785556/26246  . you may try that through ssh

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I try this next time I face the problem and let you know the results.