# how to wake up ubuntu budgie 18 from sleep

Tags: budgie, wakeup

Super simple question but how to wake up Ubuntu from sleep?

I'm just smashing the keyboard and mouse a couple times and then it works, but I couldn't figure out which action actually initiates the wake-up.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html.en explains your motherboard and its BIOS either may not support Sleep as specified, or the BIOS settings may be incorrect. For example, the Sleep state may be set incorrectly (more on that in last paragraph).

Move the mouse and/or type on the keyboard. If that does not work, power cycle the PC off, then on again.

The aforementioned link provides more troubleshooting information, as does [Where to troubleshoot wake-up from 'suspend'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784714/where-to-troubleshoot-wake-up-from-suspend) https://onlinehelp.ncr.com/Retail/Workstations/7613/HTML/Topics/UserGuide/5.%20Power%20Management/3-ACPI%20Sleep%20States%20(S0%20-%20S5).htm and https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/which-sleep-mode-should-i-use-s1-or-s3.1238872/ .

Comment: The sleep is working, I just want to know which exact action wakes up my PC, "move the mouse and type on the keyboard" is the thing I am doing but It seems quite random and I want to know If there is a key I have to press like space.

Comment: There may be a key marked as 'Sleep' (typically the icon used is a crescent moon), but since you did not specify your make and model, I can't tell. When asked to provide a model number for any technical issue, please always get the number off the serial number sticker; other 'model' information anywhere else on a PC is probably not the model number needed to find a manual.

Comment: I build the PC by myself, I figured out that the power button is the way to go, bc its starts the PC with just one click but its right under my desk so a bit inconvenient to hit

Comment: If you built it yourself, then you can add longer cabling to bring the power on button to a convenient location. I would not recommend a  remote switch which turns the entire computer off (e.g., https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07KFMNJLH/ref=sspa_dk_detail_0 ) because that would run down the CMOS battery.